# How can I pull the checked items from CheckBoxList in a repeater?

Tags: vb.net, linq, repeater, checkboxlist

I have a repeater "Statements" that is constructed as such:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Statements" runat="server"><ItemTemplate><ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <asp:Label Text='<%#("Problem Statement: " + Eval("Statement"))%>' runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label Text='<%#("Goal: " + Eval("Goal"))%>' runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="Objectives" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </li>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I've tried to pull all of the checked items from a repeated `CheckBoxList`, but so far, no luck. The below gives me an invalid cast error, but my other attempts have resulted in failure as well. How can I pull all of the checked items from the repeated lists using LINQ?

```
Dim list = _
  (From c As Control In Me.FindControl("Statements").Controls _
  Where c.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBoxList) _
  Select c).ToList()

Dim selected = _
  From c As CheckBoxList In list.AsEnumerable() _
  Select c.Items.AsQueryable().Cast(Of ListItem).Select(Function(l) l.Selected = True)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spin through the RepeaterItems of the Statements repeater and grab all the selected checkboxes using linq (on AlternatingItem and Item types only).

```
        Dim lstAllSelected As New List(Of ListItem)

        Statements.Items.ForEach(Sub(rpi As RepeaterItem)
                                     If rpi.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse rpi.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
                                         Dim lstNewItems As List(Of ListItem) = (From li As ListItem In CType(rpi.FindControl("Objectives"), CheckboxList).Items _
                                                                                 Where li.Selected).ToList()
                                         If Not lstNewItems Is Nothing AndAlso lstNewItems.Count > 0 Then
                                             lstAllSelected.AddRange(lstNewItems)
                                         End If
                                     End If
                                 End Sub)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a list of selected `ListItem`s from each repeater item.

```
Dim selected = (From itm As RepeaterItem In Statements.Items
            From li As ListItem In DirectCast(itm.FindControl("Objectives"), CheckBoxList).Items
            Where li.Selected
            Select li).ToList
```